how do I restrict users to execute SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 0 in SQL Server
We had set up a server configuration of QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT to restrict expensive queries, but as it turns out some clients started using the statement :-
SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT 0

to unset this restriction. Now, is there a way to restrict this because as using set statements requires membership in the public role., which come by default with any login. Also changing server level public role is also not recommend.

I don't think permissions are granular enough to do what you need.
The QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT session value is memory only. This makes it a bit difficult to check or add a hack (DML trigger) for control. A DML trigger on a system table to check every non-system request from those in a custom server group seems like a bad idea, even if it would work.
This seems more like a language restriction. You can audit for the statement text, but that's more work and does not stop the client from running the query in advance.
I think an estimated query cost is a bit ambiguous. If a limit on CPU, IO, and memory use can be used instead, the resource governor might work. A RESOURCE POOL to limit the percent use of CPU, IO, and memory? And a WORKLOAD GROUP to set maximum limits on CPU, mem, and MAXDOP?
A feature request to add the estimated query cost and IO limits (e.g., logical_read) could be of brutal value in our test environments.
